# Range is not defined error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, defined

Here is the script in Google Sheets I am trying to run...

Can you please give some advice on this error?

```
function myFunction() {
//IF target range D23 is edited...
//
  if (range.getRow()!=23 || range.getColumn()!=4) return;
//Set B23 to current date and time
//
  range.offset(0,-2,1,1).setValue(new Date());
//Clear range B37:T37
//
  range.offset(14,-2,1,19).clearContent();//<<<not really necessary
//Copy range B23:T36
//Paste to range B24:T37
//
  range.offset(0,-2,14,19).copyTo(range.offset(1,0));
//Clear range B23:T23
  range.offset(0,0,1,19).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: In what line happens the error?

Comment: So this looks like an onEdit function but the event parameter has not been included.  The range is e.range.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
if (range.getRow()!=23 || range.getColumn()!=4) return;
```

You're trying to fetch the row and column from range variable, but you have not defined that.

So that's why it's throwing that error.

You must define `range` before trying to use it.

If you're running this function based on some trigger then maybe you can get the range from the event object like this

```
function functionName(eventObject) {
    var range = eventObject.range;
    //Your other code follows below
}
```

Otherwise, you can also use : `getRange()`

References :

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your function should look something like this:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  if (e.range.getRow()!=23 || e.range.getColumn()!=4) return;
  e.range.offset(0,-2,1,1).setValue(new Date());
  e.range.offset(14,-2,1,19).clearContent();
  e.range.offset(0,-2,14,19).copyTo(e.range.offset(1,0));
  e.range.offset(0,0,1,19).clearContent();
}
```